# Failure to display anything in ListViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I have a ListView in a CustomScrollView widget that should display some text but the problem is that it does not display anything.
if i remove the CustomScrollView widget, the problem will be solved!
But i need to use CustomScrollView
What is the problem?

```
             CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                           return Text("${index}");
                        },
                        itemCount: 5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give listview properties `shrinkWrap: true` and try with expanded or without expanded

Answer (score 1):

You could use CustomScrollView slightly differently to achieve that:

```
CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverFillRemaining(
          hasScrollBody: true,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text("${index}");
            },
            itemCount: 5,
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SliverList` inside `CustomScrollView`.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      childCount: 5,
      (context, index) {
        return Text("${index}");
      },
    )),
  ],
),
```

Find more about [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html)